# PHP program to create a square block of "*" characters surrounded by '@' characters

Tags: php, html

Trying to create some code to make a block like:

```
 @@@@@@@
 @*****@
 @*****@
 @*****@
 @*****@
 @*****@
 @@@@@@@
```

The length of the square box is determined by the $size variable.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$size = 7;
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
      for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++){
    if($i = 0 || $i = $size-1){
      echo('@');
    }elseif($j = 0 || $j = $size-1)
      echo('@');
    else
      echo('*');
  }
  echo("</br>");

}
?>
```

However the output for this code is:

```
@@@@@@@
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Why is it only doing one iteration of the outer for-loop?

2) Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` is the comparison operator, not `=`. You have that problem in multiple places, for example;

```
if($i = 0 || $i = $size-1){
```

should probably be

```
if($i == 0 || $i == $size-1) {
```

Comment: Also use `<pre>` tag around the output

Comment: Ah Okay, this worked. Thank you. Sorry I just started PHP!

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing but defining `$i` and `$j` in your `if` and `elseif`. You have to use `==` instead of `=`.

1. So there is not only one iteration but you are resetting `$i` and `$j` at each loop.
2. It all depends of what you want to do: if you want it properly aligned, you can use the `<pre>` tag to output it in a fixed-width font.

The corrected code looks like this:

```
<pre>
<?php
$size = 7;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++)
    {
        if ($i == 0 || $i == $size - 1)
        {
            echo('@');
        }
        elseif ($j == 0 || $j == $size-1)
        {
            echo('@');
        }
        else
        {
            echo('*');
        }
    }
    echo("</br>");
}
?>
</pre>
```

Raw Output:`<pre>@@@@@@@</br>@*****@</br>@*****@</br>@*****@</br>@*****@</br>@*****@</br>@@@@@@@</br></pre>`

Browser output:

```
@@@@@@@
@*****@
@*****@
@*****@
@*****@
@*****@
@@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function like this

```
<?php 

function drawBox($size) {
    $return = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++) {
           if($i==0 || $j==0) 
               $return .= "@";
           elseif($i==$size-1 || $j == $size-1)
               $return .= "@<br/>";
           else
               $return .= "*";
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

echo drawBox(7);
?>
```